# Why all <tr> go in <thead> after calling a createTHead

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a question regarding this code:

```
const table = document.createElement("TABLE");
const thead = table.createTHead();
const tr = thead.insertRow();
const th1 = tr.insertCell();
th1.textContent = "header1";
const th2 = tr.insertCell();
th2.textContent = "header2";

const tr2 = table.insertRow();
const td1= tr2.insertCell();
td1.textContent = "field1";
const td2 = tr2.insertCell();
td2.textContent = "field2";

document.getElementById("main").appendChild(table);
```

All rows insert in `table` (not in `header`) go in `<thead>`. Why?

Why they are not going in a `<tbody>` (or a least outside of this `<thead>` as I am not doing a `thead.insertRow()` but a `table.insertRow();`

cf https://jsfiddle.net/n1b87vt3/

Comment: This is actually interesting, as [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) says: "_inserts a new row (`<tr>`) in a given `<table>` ... If a table has multiple `<tbody>` elements, by default, the new row is inserted into the last `<tbody>`_". Based on this, I'd assume the tbody would be used also when the table contains a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't create a `<tbody>`, so you insert all in `<thead>`. Add also tbody `const tbody = table.createTBody()` then insert the new row in it `tbody.insertRow()`:

```js
  const table = document.createElement("TABLE");
  const thead = table.createTHead();
  const tr = thead.insertRow();
  const th1 = tr.insertCell();
  th1.textContent = "header1";
  const th2 = tr.insertCell();
  th2.textContent = "header2";

  const tbody = table.createTBody();
  const tr2 = tbody.insertRow();
  const td1= tr2.insertCell();
  td1.textContent = "field1";
  const td2 = tr2.insertCell();
  td2.textContent = "field2";

  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(table);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

thead {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Argh, why this function is not referenced in https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp ?

Comment: @Benjamin There seems to be a lot of missing features on that page, please don't rely on w3Schools, rather use some proper documentation, like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement).

Comment: @Benjamin: because W3Schools is a terrible resource, a bane on good (sensible, secure) practice and seems to be a real-world implementation of a negative buff (think a wisdom/insight modifier of around `-2`). As Teemu says: MDN is the place to find useful web-related information.